# How can i select Item during dodraging C#,#listview,#dodrag

Tags: listview, c#-4.0

somebody help me :(..

I using winform project in visual studio
I'm making FTP program now.
In this project i want to select listviewitem that, at under my cursor (hovered) during draging another item.

i tried to figure out this problem but it doesn't works
my crudential solution is below process

1. make boolean variable and initialize false
2. when Dodrag event begin set the variable true
3. then statement in listview's mousemove event do select the item

```
if (LocalDragEnter)
            {
                ListViewItem hoverItem = Local_Listview.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
                if (!(hoverItem == null))
                {
                    hoverItem.Selected = true;
                }
            }
```

but it doesn't work at same time
select item when the dragevent is terminate

what can i DO!!! please do me a favor

Answer (score 0):

use DragOver event

```
private void Local_Listview_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listview = sender as ListView;
        var item = listview.HitTest(listview.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))).Item;            
        if (item != null)
        {
            if(item.ImageIndex == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listview.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    listview.Items[i].Selected = false;
                }
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```